# how to retrieve id from browser url in php

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

How can i retrieve id from url.user can open other users profile and send message. for that i am trying to get id of the other users. in my url id showing. Is there anyway to get id from this.

my url - http://test.com/test/index.php/dashboard/profile/15

id = 15

```
function reference_msg()
{
   alert("hi");
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            from_id:<?php echo this->session->userdata('customers_id') ?>,
            to_id :                           // here i want to get other profilers id
            subject: '<?php echo this->input->post('subject') ?>',
            message_body: '<?php echo this->input->post('body') ?>',
        },
        url: "<?php echo site_url("messages/send_via_ajax"); ?>",
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        dataType: "html",
        async: false,
        success: function(msg) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$this->uri->segment(3)`

So your code would be updated to be

`to_id : <?=$this->uri->segment(3)?>`

[More about CI URI Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)